# Initialising a virtual class from a byte array using memcpy

Tags: c++

My app receives a `byte[]` via the network which contains the memberwise representation of a fixed-size struct which is out of my control. Let's call it `Data`:

```
struct Data {
  int id;
  int count;
}
```

This worked fine:

```
char buffer[]; // filled with bytes from the network...

Data data;
memcpy(&data, data, sizeof(Data));
```

Now, I want to make the `Data` type inherit from a class with a (pure) virtual function:

```
struct Data : public SomethingVirtual {
  int id;
  int count;
}
```

And the above code no longer works. For a virtual class, the first N bytes of the instance appear to contain a pointer to the vtable, and so the data is offset.

I could increase the pointer for the call to `memcpy`, but I'm now wondering if this approach is misguided. I would like to avoid having too many layers of indirection or memory copying if possible. Also the approach should work across architectures and compilers ideally, although I'm primarily targeting i686 using g++.

What is a good solution to this problem?

Comment: Have a look at `boost::serialization`

Comment: Perhaps have a look at [boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html), as well as [boost mpi](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/mpi.html).

Comment: Copying an object like this only works for 'trivially copyable' types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you derive from something and it has virtual memebers its no longer POD.  You best solution is to serialize into your data structure then build your virtual class ontop of the trivial data.

```
struct  Data
{...}

struct AddedValue : public SomethingVirtual 
{
   AddedValue(Data)
private:
   Data MyData;
}
```

Comment: BTW the link on your profile to your Dot Generator is dead :)

Answer (score 2):

You may not use memcpy on non POD types. Possible solution would be to use aggregation instead of inheritance. And have Data as member value, that still would be POD type and thus can be used in memcpy.

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer. I guess you're saying a similar thing to @rerun, but I gave the question to him as the code sample provided a concrete idea.